# ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications error crashes Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have a React app that was originally set up with Nx workspace v12.3.4. The package.json looked like this:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "nx": "nx",
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test",
    "lint": "nx workspace-lint && nx lint",
    "e2e": "nx e2e",
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "nx affected:build",
    "affected:e2e": "nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:test": "nx affected:test",
    "affected:lint": "nx affected:lint",
    "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "nx affected",
    "format": "nx format:write",
    "format:write": "nx format:write",
    "format:check": "nx format:check",
    "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
    "help": "nx help",
    "workspace-generator": "nx workspace-generator"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ahryman40k/ts-fhir-types": "^4.0.36",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.3",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^2.3.1",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.3.1",
    "@microsoft/teams-js": "^1.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.5",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/lodash.chunk": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.flattendeep": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.has": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.set": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/lodash.startcase": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.unset": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/react-typist": "^2.0.1",
    "adaptivecards": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "botframework-webchat": "^4.11.0",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "document-register-element": "1.13.1",
    "fhirpath": "^2.7.1",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "jsonpath": "^1.1.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "lodash.chunk": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.filter": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.find": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.flatmap": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.flattendeep": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.has": "^4.5.2",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.map": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.omit": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.pick": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "lodash.startcase": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash.uniqwith": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.unset": "^4.5.2",
    "markdown-it": "^10.0.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.37",
    "msal": "^1.2.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.6.347",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.18.0",
    "proportional-scale": "^4.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-contenteditable": "^3.3.5",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
    "react-js-pull-to-refresh": "^1.2.2",
    "react-query": "^3.21.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-to-print": "^2.12.3",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.5",
    "react-use": "^15.3.4",
    "react-virtuoso": "^1.0.0",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^1.6.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "simple-update-in": "^2.2.0",
    "thenby": "^1.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "use-mobile-detect-hook": "^1.0.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-streams-polyfill": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/cosmos": "^3.16.1",
    "@babel/core": "7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.9.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "12.3.4",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "12.3.4",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.3.4",
    "@nrwl/jest": "12.3.4",
    "@nrwl/react": "12.3.4",
    "@nrwl/tao": "12.3.4",
    "@nrwl/web": "12.3.4",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.8",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.4",
    "@types/lodash.filter": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.find": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.flatmap": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.map": "^4.6.13",
    "@types/lodash.merge": "^4.6.7",
    "@types/lodash.omit": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.pick": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.set": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.6",
    "@types/lodash.uniqwith": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/react": "17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.7",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.19.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.2",
    "babel-jest": "26.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "cypress": "^8.4.1",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
    "glob": "^7.2.0",
    "jest": "26.2.2",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.5",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.1.4",
    "utility-types": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2"
  }
}
```

Now we have upgraded the Nx workspace to v14.8.6

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "nx": "nx",
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test",
    "lint": "nx workspace-lint && nx lint",
    "e2e": "nx e2e",
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "nx affected:build",
    "affected:e2e": "nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:test": "nx affected:test",
    "affected:lint": "nx affected:lint",
    "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "nx affected",
    "format": "nx format:write",
    "format:write": "nx format:write",
    "format:check": "nx format:check",
    "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
    "help": "nx help",
    "workspace-generator": "nx workspace-generator"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ahryman40k/ts-fhir-types": "^4.0.36",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.3",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^2.3.1",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.3.1",
    "@microsoft/teams-js": "^1.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.5",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/lodash.chunk": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.flattendeep": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.has": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.set": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/lodash.startcase": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.unset": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/react-typist": "^2.0.1",
    "adaptivecards": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "botframework-webchat": "^4.15.8",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "document-register-element": "1.13.1",
    "fhirpath": "^2.7.1",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "jsonpath": "^1.1.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "lodash.chunk": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.filter": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.find": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.flatmap": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.flattendeep": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.has": "^4.5.2",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.map": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.omit": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.pick": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "lodash.startcase": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash.uniqwith": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.unset": "^4.5.2",
    "markdown-it": "^10.0.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.37",
    "msal": "^1.2.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.6.347",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.18.0",
    "proportional-scale": "^4.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-contenteditable": "^3.3.5",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
    "react-js-pull-to-refresh": "^1.2.2",
    "react-query": "^3.21.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-to-print": "^2.12.3",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.5",
    "react-use": "^15.3.4",
    "react-virtuoso": "^1.0.0",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^1.6.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "simple-update-in": "^2.2.0",
    "thenby": "^1.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "use-mobile-detect-hook": "^1.0.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-streams-polyfill": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/cosmos": "^3.16.1",
    "@babel/core": "7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.9.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.8.6",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.8.6",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.8.6",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.8.6",
    "@nrwl/react": "14.8.6",
    "@nrwl/web": "14.8.6",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.8.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.4",
    "@types/lodash.filter": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.find": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.flatmap": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.map": "^4.6.13",
    "@types/lodash.merge": "^4.6.7",
    "@types/lodash.omit": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.pick": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.set": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.6",
    "@types/lodash.uniqwith": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/node": "18.7.18",
    "@types/react": "17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.7",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.19.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.2",
    "babel-jest": "28.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "cypress": "^8.4.1",
    "dotenv": "10.0.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "glob": "^7.2.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.3",
    "nx": "14.8.6",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "utility-types": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2"
  }
}
```

After the upgrade, one of the issues we encountered was an uncaught runtime error: "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded". To suppress this error, we added following code to the wepack.config.js:

```
module.exports = (config) => {
  config = babelWebpackConfig(config)
  
  if (config.devServer) {
    config.devServer = {
      ...config.devServer,
      client: {
        ...config.devServer.client,
        overlay: {
          ...config.devServer.client.overlay,
          runtimeErrors: (error) => {
            if (
              error.message.includes("ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded") 
              )
            ) {
              return false
            }
            return true
          },
        },
      },
    }
  }

  return config
}
```

However when we run our e2e tests, we encounter another runtime error: "ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications". I tried to add this error in webpack.config.js to suppress it, as with the other one. Although we don't get this error during the e2e tests, but it crashes Cypress. Any idea why?